# bootstrap3 thumbnail grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I find a tutorial about bootstrap grid, but it was written in bootstrap1.x. Now I want to use bootstrap3 to achieve the same effect. The doc says using **.img-thumbnail** instead of **.media-grid**, but it seems still not work. What I want is something like this:
[image]

The 1.x version is:

```html
<ul class="media-grid">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/290x200" />
                </a>
            </li>

    <!-- row of 4 thumbnails -->
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x140" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x140" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x140" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/210x140" />
                </a>
            </li>       

        </ul><!-- end media-grid -->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.img-thumbnail` class is applied to images so they get that rounded border style, it's not a direct replacement for `.media-grid`, also if you want the images to be wrapped in a link then you're better off using the `.thumbnail` class on the link itself as [described here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).

To build the actual grid you need to use Bootstrap 3's [new grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), your example would look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="..." />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/ZQ3sG/3/show/)**

And here's **[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/ZQ3sG/2/show/)** if you don't need the links, just the thumbnail grid

Comment: thanks for your reply. Using div to achieve is fine, but does it possible to achieve by ul element?

Comment: check [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/) live demo for thumbnail grid, hope helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
       Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
       Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       Some Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
       Some Image
    </div>
</div>
```